# react cannot GET from express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I tried to connect my react.js front end with my express.js server in the backend, but I got this error.

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

**Here is the code**

I have written this line of code inside package.json for the react app to allow access to the express app port

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

This is the express.js code I have written to respond for the GET request

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.json({"message": "Hello World"});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`The express server is listening at port ${port}...`));
```

And this is the react code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("initial state");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/").then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      }
    }).then(responseData => setResponse(responseData));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{response}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the response is ? You can debug it in the browser, or go direct to the URL. Also "Hello World" is not JSON

Comment: @Pogrindis — The result of passing {“message”: “Hello world”} through res.json **is** JSON

Comment: You can't do `if (res.ok) {` before you convert the data to json. You will need to do something like this: `fetch("/").then(data => data.json()).then(` and then you can check for the `res.ok` object

Comment: @Dominik — Yes, you can

Comment: Today I learned

Comment: I don’t have the time to build a test case but [the docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) say that only requests that don’t `Accept` HTML responses will be proxied. I’ve no idea what `Accept` header `fetch` will send by default but you aren’t overriding it and it might include `text/html`.

Comment: Have you tried straight up using fetch("http://localhost:3001/") instead of just fetch("/")? there might be an issue with how you set up the proxy

Comment: I tried fetch("http://localhost:3001/") and it didn't work

Comment: This is the response after loging it

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by deleting the package-lock.json and node_modules files. Then I have reset the app by the command

```
npm install
```

Finally, I changed the routing to "/api" in both react.js and express.js apps to make it distinct from the root route of the react app.

**the express code**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3001;

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.json({message: "Hello World"});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`The express server is listening at port ${port}...`));
```

**the react code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState("initial state");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api").then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      }
    }).then(responseData => setResponse(responseData.message));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{response}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck like you,
I solved the problem when I restart react server
you made a change to package.json through insert

( "proxy":"http://localhost:3001" )

so you should restart react to let react know your edition